# Pass a JsonObject in Volley as POST parameter

Tags: android

I have an API endpoint which needs parameters to be sent as JsonObject in a POST request.

The response which I will get is not Json, but rather a small CSV string.

The Code is

```
stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://apitest.eezyrent.com/api/userauthentication/SignUp",
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplication(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> jsonParams2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsonParams2.put("vcFName", firstname.getText().toString());
                jsonParams2.put("vcLname", lastname.getText().toString());
                jsonParams2.put("vcMobileNo", phone_no.getText().toString());
                jsonParams2.put("vcGender", gender_short);
                jsonParams2.put("vcEmailAddress", email.getText().toString());
                jsonParams2.put("vcPassword", password.getText().toString());
                jsonParams2.put("vcFBID", "");
                jsonParams2.put("intLoginUserID", "");
                jsonParams2.put("SignUpFrom", "Web");
                jsonParams2.put("intloginid", "");
                jsonParams2.put("AlreadyRegister", "");
                return jsonParams2;
            }

        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put( "charset", "utf-8");
            return headers;
        }
    };
```

The above code is heavily inspired by using answers from this community, but this does not seem to solve the problem for me.

I get Volley Error 405.

```
 E/Volley﹕ [112549] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 405 for http://myurl
```

Infact If I used AsyncTask instead of Volley, With the same json as parameters and the same endpoint url. It works!! The AsyncTask code was found from this question. [Java HttpClient changing content-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263854/java-httpclient-changing-content-type)

But I want to use Volley, What could be the solution to this?

Sample JSON Object

```
{"vcFName":"Ron","vcLname":"Weasley","vcMobileNo":"555888999","vcGender":"M","vcEmailAddress":"someone@somewhere.com","vcPassword":"123456","vcFBID":"","intLoginUserID":'',"SignUpFrom":"Web","intloginid":"","AlreadyRegister":""}
```

Comment: you can make `JsonObjectRequest ` see this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: @KaranMer I have tried that and I get the same error. Also JsonObjectRequest is not usefull for me since the response is CSV string and not JSON string.

Comment: in that case you need to make custom request see this SO thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30859044/post-json-object-data-to-get-json-array-response-using-volley-in-android

Comment: @KaranMer but again that helper class is for JsonArrayRequest  and not StringRequest. Can You modify that helper class since I donot understand it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JsonObjectRequest class. Pass your params as json object in the 3rd parameter of the JsonObjectRequest class. Below is a small snippet:

```
 Map<String, String> jsonParams2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
            jsonParams2.put("vcFName", firstname.getText().toString());
            jsonParams2.put("vcLname", lastname.getText().toString());
            jsonParams2.put("vcMobileNo", phone_no.getText().toString());
            jsonParams2.put("vcGender", gender_short);
            jsonParams2.put("vcEmailAddress", email.getText().toString());
            jsonParams2.put("vcPassword", password.getText().toString());
            jsonParams2.put("vcFBID", "");
            jsonParams2.put("intLoginUserID", "");
            jsonParams2.put("SignUpFrom", "Web");
            jsonParams2.put("intloginid", "");
            jsonParams2.put("AlreadyRegister", "");

JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.POST,
        YourUrl, new JsonObject(jsonParams2),
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
        headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.put( "charset", "utf-8");
        return headers;
    }
};
```

Comment: As I replied to @KaranMer, I have already tried this. and found the same error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Make model class parsable/Serializable.
Step 2: Override toString() in model class.
Step 3:
     `Map<String,JSONObject> params = new HashMap<>();
        JSONObject object = null;
        try{
            object = new JSONObject(classObject.toString());
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
        params.put("key", object);
        JSONObject objectParams = new JSONObject(params);`
Step 4: Send objectParams with volley JSONObject request.
Done!!!